# Where is the specification for conversion in JavaScript's left shift (<<) operator

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I would like to determine where my lack of knowledge is with respect to JavaScript's number handling. The gap shows up in the way that JS handles the shift left operator.

It is my understanding that in in JavaScript "all numbers are floating point". But that doesn't fit with bit shifting operators, and indeed, the demonstrable behavior also tells me there's more to this than I'm aware of.

I checked the specification here: [bitshift operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-bitwise-shift-operators) and all it says (at this point) is

> The Left Shift Operator ( << ) Performs a bitwise left shift operation on the left operand by the amount specified by the right operand.

But if all numbers are in fact represented as a floating point format, then this, taken literally would mean we'd be shifting the bit representations of mantissa and exponent, and would get total nonsense values as the exponent bits moved into the mantissa bits. So, my next thought was that perhaps it just takes the mantissa part, shifts that, and puts it back. But that doesn't appear to be the case either, since 2.5 << 1 is 4, not 5.

I also found that any number with a large exponent value seems to result in zeroes.

So, my guess, from this brief examination, is that the system actually takes the number, performs a conversion that would be described as "chop out a 32 bit two's complement integer value" and then does a shift on that, before converting the resulting int back to a floating representation. (Unless I was lied to about the "all numbers are floats" in the first place!)

Can anyone tell me:

a) was I lied to about the "all numbers are floats" thing?
b) if I'm right in my guess about the "convert to int, shift, then convert back" behavior, where is that documented. I'm have to believe it's in the spec, but it's a big one, and while I've done some searching, I've not read it all (nor do I particularly want to if I can get a hint!)

Comment: a) no, b) looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found in the abstract operation [`Number::leftShift`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-leftShift):

> 1. Let lnum be ! ToInt32(x).
> 2. Let rnum be ! ToUint32(y).

Whereas ToInt32 basically performs:

> Let int32bit be int modulo 2³²

Comment: Oh, another entire segment of the docs, many thanks, that's very helpful.

Comment: @TobyEggitt See http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-left-shift-operator and http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-numeric-types